# Is it possible to mark a Maven dependency as "lower priority" during mediation if it conflicts transitively?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I'm creating a test helper library that uses fixtures from several other projects. Some of these projects may actually use this test helper as part of their own tests. This seems circular, but it turns out not to be due to a multi-module setup; only the main service module's tests would use the test helper library, while the client, emulator, and fixture modules remain free of that dependency:

```
- project foo
  - foo-service
    -> test-helper-lib (in <scope>test</scope> only)
  - foo-client
  - foo-emulator
  - foo-fixture
- project bar
  - bar-service
  - bar-client
  - bar-emulator
  - bar-fixture
- project test-helper-lib
  - test-helper-lib
    -> foo-client
    -> foo-fixture
    -> bar-client
    -> bar-fixture
```

Now, to be more precise, each service's test *does* add its client, emulator, and fixture as dependencies. So it's more like:

```
- project foo
  - foo-service
    -> test-helper-lib (in <scope>test</scope> only)
    -> foo-client
    -> foo-emulator
    -> foo-fixture
  - foo-client
  - foo-emulator
  - foo-fixture
- project bar
  - bar-service
    -> bar-client
    -> bar-emulator
    -> bar-fixture
  - bar-client
  - bar-emulator
  - bar-fixture
- project test-helper-lib
  - test-helper-lib
    -> foo-client
    -> foo-fixture
    -> bar-client
    -> bar-fixture
```

You can see, then, that there can be a transitive dependency conflict between...

```
- foo-service
  - test-helper-lib
    - foo-client
```

and

```
- foo-service
  - foo-client
```

In such cases, in foo-service, I would always like test-helper-lib's versions of foo-{client,emulator,fixture} to be excluded, because I would want foo-service tests to use the latest client, emulator, and fixture, not the older one packaged with test-lib-helper. **Can I do something to "mark" test-helper-lib as having lower-priority transitive dependencies?**

Comment: Define the version you would like to have as a direct dependency which will Maven handle nearest wins...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I guess you don't really have the problem you describe in your setup. Maven has a "nearest dependency wins" rule. As your `test-helper-lib` dependencies seem to be more nested than your other dependencies, they will loose.

Generally, though, I don't like Maven dependency mediation much. As soon as your dependency tree becomes crowded, it is hard to figure out the versions that actually "win". I recommend to make heavy use of `<dependencyManagement>` which allows you to control the versions of transitive dependencies (without actually adding something to the dependency tree that you may not need).

To your concrete question: No, you cannot give more or less priority to version numbers.